# Why Hosts set storage information directly and not through the Runtime

Tags: runtime, storage, host-functions, architecture

Why Host set storage information directly and not through the `Runtime api`? (e.g. `Grandpa Authorities`, `Accounts`, `Code`, `Heap_Pages`)
Is this an expected behavior or legacy?

Comment: What do you mean "directly"?